# CRM 9 - Fetch records from a CRM entity based on ID using JavaScript WebResource

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-365, unified-service-desk

I have a entity with multiple records in it. The entity contains 3 fields **Parameter Name**, **Parameter Value**, and **Contact ID**. 
**Contact ID** is a lookup field. There are multiple records for a same **Contact ID** in my CRM Entity.

Now I want to fetch all **Parameter Name** and **Parameter Value** from CRM Entity based on the **Contact ID**.

I am using following code,

```
var Query = "$select=vrp_parametername&$filter= vrp_contactid eq '" + contactid + "'";
 XrmSvcToolkit.retrieveMultiple({
    entityName: entity ,  
    odataQuery: Query,
    async: false,
    successCallback: successCallback,
    errorCallback: errorCallback
});
```

But I am getting following error,

> Error has occurred in retrieving Response - Error: 400: Bad Request: No property 'vrp_contactid' exists in type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity' at position 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mixing the Schema Name with Logical Name in CRM in this case. I was using Schema Name in CRM which was why this error was coming.

What I did was simply used the Logical Name in this case and was able to achieved the desired result.

Thank you all for the help

Comment: can you put the query you used finally?

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly states that for that particular entity it could not find vrp_contactid field.
Why don’t you check if field is available.
Try using Crm restbuilder and see which condition attribute is available.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `_vrp_contactid_value`

```
var Query = "$select=vrp_parametername&$filter=_vrp_contactid_value eq '" + contactid + "'";
```

**Update**:

You can use the filter using single valued navigation property, refer [my blog](https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/arunvinothdynamicsspot/archive/2019/03/18/lookup-filtering-in-powerapps-vs-web-api-vs-odata) on same topic. There is another version of this query below:

```
var Query = "$select=vrp_parametername&$filter=vrp_contactid/contactid eq '" + contactid + "'";
```

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/query-data-web-api#filter-records-based-on-single-valued-navigation-property)

Comment: But the field name is vrp_contactid

Comment: @FaranSaleem https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/arunvinothdynamicsspot/archive/2019/03/17/lookup-filtering-in-powerapps-vs-web-api-vs-odata

Comment: @FaranSaleem see my update, also make sure you close all your SO questions by upvoting/accepting the answer that helped you.